# Making Genymotion get the same IP of my wifi network

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm developing an app that needs to communicate directly with a desktop application that runs on a computer that is connected to my wifi network. I'm using a device to develop (that's easy because the computer and my phone are connected to the same network), but I'd like to use Genymotion instead. However, I just can't manage to make Genymotion work as another host of my network, so that it could reach the computer that's running the other application. I tried changing VirtualBox settings to use a bridged adapter, but I got no luck. It would be nice if I could someway assign to my virtual device the IP of the laptop I'm running Genymotion on. Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you want to assign your genymotion an address from your wifi network your pc is connected to? All you want is: making sure your data passes through all the layers right? that is what is happening when you use genytmotion, the virtual address of the emulator  is not like loopback address. If you want to check this you can try connecting your genymotion to d/t computer on your wifi

Comment: I'm running a server on my Android app. The virtual device is getting an IP like 10.0.x.x and my wifi network is like 192.168.x.x. Having that said, my app is not reachable by the desktop application.

Comment: [Might be of interest](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/C9DHmEF_8vA/4_zCs-zaSNIJ)

Comment: Thanks, @Skynet, but I know that VirtualBox is more powerful than the Android emulator when it comes to networking settings. I'm curious if there is something that can be done with that.

Comment: Oh I see, I will put my suggestion as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution here: http://blog.cloud-mes.com/2014/01/22/enable-genymotion-android-emulator-network-in-enerprise-intranet/

I just needed to set the adapter as bridged mode. The trick was to set the **second** adapter, not the first one as I did before (the first one is meant to stay as it is, using vboxnet0 interface). It couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Port Forwarding**.

In Ubuntu ([details here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding)), execute these 3 commands:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

---

```
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d yourIP --dport   
portNumberOfTheServerRunningONTheEmulator -j DNAT --to-destination yourEmulatorsIP
```

---

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

---

I tried this on my machine my emulators ip was `192.168.56.101` and my PC's IP address was `10.0.20.159`. So I run these commands:

```
 sudo isysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

---

assume the server program is running on port 5555

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.20.159 --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.101
```

---

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

So then I tried to connect to the emulator from another machine on the network typing this address: `10.0.20.159:5555` (the result was **connection was reset** because I dont have actual server program running on the emulator) but when I try with d/t port say `10.0.20.159:5595` the result is **unable to connect** so my guess here is the PC was able to reach the emulator through the port forwarding)

I hope it helps try it with your actual server program running. :)